# How to load css in .phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, css, phtml

i have a custom css for specific page which is category product page, i want to include this css only when i load this page, as i know the page is located in **theme/default/template/catalog/category/page.phtml**, is there any way to do this ?

basically i have to include it like this in my phtml:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl('style/reset.css'); ?>" />
```

Comment: means you wanna load this css on specific category ??

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala no, i just need to load this css in category page

Comment: means on every category page ??

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala yes, need to load in frontend/theme/default/template/catalog/category/page.phtml

Comment: Is that CMS Page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For display css on category page. please follow as below

put your css file in your theme

ex . `skin/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/css/yourcssname.css`

in your theme's `local.xml` located in `app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/layout/local.xml`

Put below code in `layout` node.

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>yourcssname.css</name></action>
    </reference> 
</catalog_category_default>
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>yourcssname.css</name></action>
    </reference> 
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Comment: i've added it below <layout> tag and its not working

Comment: Have you put your css in skin folder ??

Comment: Yes i already put it and remove var/cache

Comment: GIve me full path of your css and also give me the code which is in local.xml that you added

Comment: <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>category-products.css</name></action>

Comment: path of your css file ??

Comment: skin/frontend/theme/default/css/category-products.css

Comment: css merging enable in your site ??

Comment: what is css merging?

Comment: Goto `System->configuration->advanced->developer`  and check css js merging yes or no